# How to keep 2 decimal places in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, decimal, digits

I have selected columns from a database table and want this data with two decimal places only. I have:

```
SQL.Strings = ('select '#9'my_index '#9'his_index,'...
```

- What is that `#9`?
- How can I deal with the data I selected to make it only keep two decimal places?

I am very new to Delphi.

Comment: What data type is in the database? What field type you've got in Delphi? Do you need your data as a string or do you need it as a numeric type rounded to only hold 2 decimal places?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`#9` is the character with code 9, TAB.

If you want to convert a floating point value to a string with 2 decimal places you use one of the formatting functions, e.g. `Format()`:

```
var
  d: Double;
  s: string;
...
d := Sqrt(2.0);
s := Format('%.2f', [d]);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
function Round2(aValue:double):double;    
begin    
  Round2:=Round(aValue*100)/100;    
end;
```

Comment: This is not _keeping_ two decimal digits, it _changes_ them: `0.0999` does not become `0.09` but instead `0.10`.

Comment: What you are talking about is not rounding but truncation to 2 decimal places

Comment: Exactly. Where do you got the idea from that OP/the question wants rounding? Because the accepted answer also rounds? OP may neither be aware of that.

Comment: ok, my fault :)

Answer (score 5):

`#9` is the tab character.

If `f` is a floating-point variable, you can do `FormatFloat('#.##', f)` to obtain a string representation of `f` with no more than 2 decimals.

Comment: Oh...you compete against each other! Thanks for both of you!

Answer (score 2):

For Float to Float (with 2 decimal places, say) rounding check [this](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Math.RoundTo) from documentation. Gives sufficient examples too. It uses banker's rounding.

```
x := RoundTo(1.235, -2); //gives 1.24
```

Note that there is a difference between simply truncating to two decimal places (like in Format()), rounding to integer, and rounding to float.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays the SysUtils unit contains the solution:

```
System.SysUtils.FloatToStrF( singleValue, 7, ffFixed, 2 );
System.SysUtils.FloatToStrF( doubleValue, 15, ffFixed, 2 );
```

You can pass +1 TFormatSettings parameter if the requiered decimal/thousand separator differ from the current system locale settings.

Answer (score 1):

The internal float format routines only work with simple numbers > 1

You need to do something more complicated for a general purpose decimal place limiter that works correctly on both fixed point and values < 1 with scientific notation.

I use this routine

```
function TForm1.Flt2str(Avalue:double; ADigits:integer):string;
var v:double; p:integer; e:string;
begin
  if abs(Avalue)<1 then
  begin
    result:=floatTostr(Avalue);
    p:=pos('E',result);
    if p>0 then
    begin
      e:=copy(result,p,length(result));
      setlength(result,p-1);
      v:=RoundTo(StrToFloat(result),-Adigits);
      result:=FloatToStr(v)+e;
    end else
      result:=FloatToStr(RoundTo(Avalue,-Adigits));
  end
  else
    result:=FloatToStr(RoundTo(Avalue,-Adigits));
end;
```

So, with digits=2, 1.2349 rounds to 1.23 and 1.2349E-17 rounds to 1.23E-17

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

```
Function RoundingUserDefineDecaimalPart(FloatNum: Double; NoOfDecPart: integer): Double;
Var
     ls_FloatNumber: String;
Begin
     ls_FloatNumber := FloatToStr(FloatNum);
     IF Pos('.', ls_FloatNumber) > 0 Then
          Result := StrToFloat
            (copy(ls_FloatNumber, 1, Pos('.', ls_FloatNumber) - 1) + '.' + copy
                 (ls_FloatNumber, Pos('.', ls_FloatNumber) + 1, NoOfDecPart))
     Else
          Result := FloatNum;
End;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Function RealFormat(FloatNum: Double): string;
Var
     ls_FloatNumber: String;
Begin
     ls_FloatNumber:=StringReplace(FloatToStr(FloatNum),',','.',[rfReplaceAll]);
     IF Pos('.', ls_FloatNumber) > 0 Then
          Result :=
            (copy(ls_FloatNumber, 1, Pos('.', ls_FloatNumber) - 1) + '.' + copy
                 (ls_FloatNumber, Pos('.', ls_FloatNumber) + 1, 2))
     Else
          Result := FloatToStr(FloatNum);
End;
```

Answer (score 1):

For N Places behind the seperator use

```
function round_n(f:double; n:nativeint):double;
var i,m : nativeint;
begin
  m := 10;
  for i := 1 to pred(n) do
    m := m * 10;

  f := f * m;
  f := round(f);
  result := f / m;      
end;
```

Comment: Works only when `n` is `1` or higher, not for _zero_ decimal digits.